# Расположение элементов в один ряд

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Есть страница на которой нужно расположить несколько элементов в ряд. И у меня получилось но почему то в 2 разных случаях понадобилось делать это по разному, не могу понять почему.

Вариант 1:

```
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("С", new { @style = "margin-right: 5px" })
                        <input type="date" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("По", new { @style = "margin-right: 5px" })
                        <input type="date" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

4 элемента расположились в ряд.
А вот есть пример где такой же подход не подошёл.
Вариант 2:

```
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 10px">
                                @Html.RadioButton("Proceeds", "Seller", true)
                                @Html.Label("По продавцу")
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.DropDownList("sellerList", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @style = "display: inline-block", @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.CheckBox("allSeller")
                                @Html.Label("По каждому")
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 10px">
                                @Html.RadioButton("Proceeds", "Auto", false)
                                @Html.Label("По автомобилю")
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.DropDownList("autoList", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @style = "display: inline-block", @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.CheckBox("allAuto")
                                @Html.Label("По каждой")
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="button" value="Выручка" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="height: 80px" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

В этом случае у дроп даун листа пришлось ставить `"display: inline-block"` иначе следующий лейбл переносится на следующую строчку. Почему так? Подскажите пожалуйста может я что то не так делаю?

Вот код из браузера:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div id="headTableProceeds">
            <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin: 0; table-layout: fixed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th id="sel" style="display: none">Продавец</th>
                        <th id="auto" style="display: none">Автомобиль</th>
                        <th id="proceeds" style="display: none">Выручка</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="bodyTableProceeds" class="container">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label for="">Фильтры детализации:</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input id="Date" name="Date" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Date" type="hidden" value="false" />
                <label for="">По дате</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" style="margin-right: 5px">С</label>
                    <input type="date" disabled />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" style="margin-right: 5px">По</label>
                    <input type="date" disabled />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 10px">
                            <input checked="checked" id="Proceeds" name="Proceeds" type="radio" value="Seller" />
                            <label for="">По продавцу</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control" id="sellerList" name="sellerList" style="display: inline-block"></select>
                            <input id="allSeller" name="allSeller" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="allSeller" type="hidden" value="false" />
                            <label for="">По каждому</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 10px">
                            <input id="Proceeds" name="Proceeds" type="radio" value="Auto" />
                            <label for="">По автомобилю</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="autoList" name="autoList" style="display: inline-block"></select>
                            <input disabled="disabled" id="allAuto" name="allAuto" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="allAuto" type="hidden" value="false" />
                            <label for="">По каждой</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input type="button" value="Выручка" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="height: 80px" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <table style="display: none" id="equipTable" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Двигатель</th>
                    <th>Мощность</th>
                    <th>Год выпуска</th>
                    <th>Тип привода</th>
                    <th>КПП</th>
                    <th>Кузов</th>
                    <th>Максимальная скорость</th>
                    <th>Вес</th>
                    <th>Бак</th>
                    <th>Цвет</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none" class="col-sm-4">
        <img id="autoPic" class="img-responsive" src="/Content/auto.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в 2 `разных` случаях понадобилось делать это `по разному` - так и должно быть, разве нет?

Comment: и причем тут C#?

Comment: @tym32167 лишний тег прицепил, ошибся. А по поводу первого комментария немного не правильно написал. Случаи одинаковые. В обоих случаях в row запихиваю несколько элементов, но почему то в первом достаточно того что это row, а во втором приходится добавлять "display: inline-block" почему эта разница не понимаю.

Comment: скиньте рабочий пример, без хелперов (скопируйте с инспектора браузера, чтобы я мог повторить данный код

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц скинул, там чуть больше кода, скинул всю страницу.

Comment: А теперь бы еще рисуночек, как вы хотите что бы было

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц скрин скинул. У меня сейчас вот так вот. Хочу понять почему для первого случая не нужно было писать `"display: inline-block"` а для второго нужно.

Comment: Убрал ваши `inline-block`: все нормально, вот [скрин](http://prntscr.com/mvynee). При каком `width` экрана вы видите что чтото не так?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц а нечего что у вас на скрине чекбоксы и лейблы идущие после дроп даун листов на следующую строку уползли?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц а у меня всё нормально с этим, как раз инлайн-блок это и решает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div id="headTableProceeds">
          <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin: 0; table-layout: fixed">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th id="sel" style="display: none">Продавец</th>
                      <th id="auto" style="display: none">Автомобиль</th>
                      <th id="proceeds" style="display: none">Выручка</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
          </table>
      </div>
      <div id="bodyTableProceeds" class="container">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
              <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <label for="">Фильтры детализации:</label>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
              <input id="Date" name="Date" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Date" type="hidden" value="false" />
              <label for="">По дате</label>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="" style="margin-right: 5px">С</label>
                  <input type="date" disabled />
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="" style="margin-right: 5px">По</label>
                  <input type="date" disabled />
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-10">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 10px">
                          <input checked="checked" id="Proceeds" name="Proceeds" type="radio" value="Seller" />
                          <label for="">По продавцу</label>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <select class="form-control" id="sellerList" name="sellerList"></select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input id="allSeller" name="allSeller" type="checkbox" value="true" />
                                <input name="allSeller" type="hidden" value="false" />
                                <label for="allSeller">По каждому</label>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 10px">
                          <input id="Proceeds" name="Proceeds" type="radio" value="Auto" />
                          <label for="">По автомобилю</label>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <select class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="autoList" name="autoList"></select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input disabled="disabled" id="allAuto" name="allAuto" type="checkbox" value="true" />
                                <input name="allAuto" type="hidden" value="false" />
                                <label for="allAuto">По каждой</label>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <input type="button" value="Выручка" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="height: 80px" />
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <table style="display: none" id="equipTable" class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Двигатель</th>
                  <th>Мощность</th>
                  <th>Год выпуска</th>
                  <th>Тип привода</th>
                  <th>КПП</th>
                  <th>Кузов</th>
                  <th>Максимальная скорость</th>
                  <th>Вес</th>
                  <th>Бак</th>
                  <th>Цвет</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td></td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
  <div style="display: none" class="col-sm-4">
      <img id="autoPic" class="img-responsive" src="/Content/auto.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Виталий вы в своём примере вытащили выпадающий список в отдельный div для чего это было сделано? Мой вопрос заключался в том почему в одном диве с другими элементами он не хочет в строчку отображаться? А если так нельзя то я лучше уж напишу `inline-block` чем буду в отдельный div вытаскивать.

Comment: @Андрей потому что класс form-groupнн обеспечивает одну строку

Comment: Виталий, спасибо.